# How can we avoid splitting the ecommerce_purchase event in firebase and send extra custom dimensions on product scope from gtm to GA?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics

how can we avoid splitting the ecommerce_purchase event in firebase and send extra custom dimensions on product scope from gtm to GA?

We have used option 2 in this guide, and send events to both firebase and google analytics via gtm: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/02/how-do-i-add-firebase-analytics-to-app.html

We send an event for ecommerce_purchase following this guide: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v5/enhanced-ecommerce#purchases

This does give us functioning enhanced ecommerce data in google analytics, but there are also some issues:

1. We also send some custom event parameters within the ecommerce_purchase event to firebase. As well as to google analytics.
   The custom event parameters (sent as custom dimensions to GA) does not show up in GA.
2. An issue is that in firebase the ecommerce_purchase events are split in 2, "ecommerce_purchase" and "(not set)":
   [image: ecommerce_purchase event]
   [image: (not set) event]

Google Tag Manager configuration:
[image: Ecommerce purchase tag]
[image: Ecommerce purchase trigger]
[image: Google Analytics settings variable]

Comment: Would be very grateful for help on this issue :)

Comment: Was there any resolution on this please? Facing the same issue here. Many thanks

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid not. I continued with another project.
If I would go back to this I would try to join the data in biqquery. All firebase data are exported there.